# AngularJS: Using Custom Directives inside ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a custom directive, but am having issues with using it inside of ngRepeat. For example, in my taco example below, the objects that are being aliased as `taco` in the ng-repeat attribute seem to be unaccessible from within the definition of the  directive.

`app.tpl.html`

```html
<div ng-repeat="taco in tacoController.tacos">
    <taco></taco>
<div>
```

`taco.directive.js`

```js
(function() {
    angular
        .module('food')
        .directive('taco', [
            // DI: strings here
            function(
                // DI: params here
            ) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    template: `
                        // THIS WORKS
                        <div>{{ tacoController.lastShipment }}</div>
                        // THIS DOES NOT!
                        <div>{{ taco.shellType }}</div>
                    `
                };
            }
        ])
})();
```

p.s. I would like to avoid using isolate scope in my directive if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have access to `tacoController` because it lives in scope of the main page and you don't have isolated scope in custom directive.
On the other hand `taco` item in `ng-repeat` does not live in scope of the main page and thus it is not accessible in custom directive.

You can pass `taco` item in directive's isolated scope as following (you may already know that):

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('food')
        .directive('taco', [
            // DI: strings here
            function(
                // DI: params here
            ) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: {
                        tacoItem: '=',
                        lastShipment: '='
                    },
                    template: `
                        // THIS WORKS
                        <div>{{ lastShipment }}</div>
                        // THIS DOES NOT!
                        <div>{{ tacoItem.shellType }}</div>
                    `
                };
            }
        ])
})();
```

Then html should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="taco in tacoController.tacos">
    <taco taco-item="taco" last-shipment="tacoController.lastShipment"></taco>
<div>
```

Comment: So it sounds like if I want access to the `taco` objects from within my directive, there's no way around using isolate scope...?

Comment: Do you mean if it is necessary to have isolated scope in directive or shared scope with the main page in order for the directive to have access to `taco` object? Generally it is a good practice for directives to have isolated scopes. If you want to pass more information - data from outside you are always able to do so.

Comment: The reason I was hoping to avoid the isolate scopes route is because I suspect this will create an experience similar to using React w/o Redux (i.e. passing along props through multiple levels in the component hierarchy). I agree that isolate scopes is a best practice, but it enforces API contracts between everything which can be a real pain if you're not using a state container like Redux or MobX. Thanks so much for your input though!